# changing body background color for custom post type in admin backend

Tags: admin

i have a custom post type called 'auctions', and i'd like to be able to visually differentiate auctions from posts and pages **in the backend** by assigning a different background color to the auction post type.

this could be easily achieved if i had a way to assign a body class to admin pages pertaining to this specific post type, except i'm not sure as to how i'd go about that :).

any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy and your css to overwrite the default style like this

```
add_action('admin_print_styles', 'auctions_admin_print_styles_332');

function auctions_admin_print_styles_332(){
   if ((isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'auctions') || (isset($post_type) && $post_type == 'auctions')){

     //include your css file using wp_enqueue_style() somthing like 
      wp_enqueue_style( 'handle name', plugins_url('/style.css', __FILE__), array(), '1.0' );

      // or a more hackish way would be to echo out the css style tag
  }
}
```

so the class you are looking for is actualy an id "wpwrap" so you can use something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
#wpwrap{background-color: #FFF;}
</style>
```

Hope this helps