# Do stuff when editing or writing a certain custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types

I would like to add extra js file to a backend when editing or creating a custom post type.

I found [pretty good answer to it](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8816/changing-body-background-color-for-custom-post-type-in-admin-backend) but it has a flaw, it wont work when editing the custom post type, only on create and archive view.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
add_action("admin_print_scripts","load_my_script");
function load_my_script() {
    global $pagenow, $typenow;
    if (is_admin() && $pagenow=='post-new.php' OR $pagenow=='post.php' && $typenow=='Custom_post_type_name') {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
```

just change `Custom_post_type_name` to the actual name of your custom post type and enqueue your script.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But for some reason it has the same flaw as the previous code, not effecting edit page.

Comment: is the script loaded? can you see it in the source?

Comment: Not seeing the script anywhere.

Comment: well then you must be doing something wrong, I use this same snippet in my latest plugin http://en.bainternet.info/2011/simple-gist-embed which works just fine. paste your code and i'll take a look

Comment: This is what I've been using http://pastie.org/2545593